# gfortran does not compile implied do loop

Tags: arrays, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to initialize an array as follows:

```
program test
  n = 3
  call it(n)

contains

subroutine it(n)
  integer n,j
  integer, dimension(3*(n-1)) :: a=(/(j,j=4,3*n,1)/)
  write(*,*) a
end subroutine it

end program test
```

When I compile with `gfortran -o test.exe test.f`, I receive the following error:

```
test.f:9.43:

        integer, dimension(3*(n-1)) :: a=(/(j,j=4,3*n,1)/)
                                           1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
```

What is the problem?  As far as I understand, this is standard-conforming code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler error may be confusing, but the example code is not standard conforming.

The *initializer* in a type declaration statement must be a *constant expression*.  Also, *automatic data objects* may not have the SAVE attribute.

Initialization (with no qualifying adjective) only ever happens once in Fortran, before the program starts executing.  Consequently the expression used in an initializer must be something that can be evaluated before your program starts executing (the details of what's permissible in such an expression (and aspects of the terminology) depend on the Fortran standard that you are writing to).

The initializer in the example code depends on the value of n, which is a dummy argument.  You cannot reference the value of a dummy argument before your program has started executing - it is inherently not a constant.

Similarly, the attributes (its shape) of the `a` local variable depend on the value of a dummy argument.  This makes the variable `a` an automatic data object.  An automatic data object is not permitted to have the SAVE attribute (the attributes of the object could potentially vary from call to call, which is inconsistent with SAVE maintaining the value from call to call).  Supplying an initializer also implies the SAVE attribute.

If `n` was a parameter and not a dummy argument, then the code would conform.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what's really going on - that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two examples of what is allowed, as already explained by IanH.  In one case the initializer is a constant expression since `M` is a parameter.  In the other, while the initialization is not a constant expression, it is not part of a declaration.

```
program test5
  integer :: j
  integer :: n = 3
  integer, parameter :: M = 4
  integer, dimension(3*(M-1)) :: b = [ (j,j=4,3*M,1) ]

  write (*,*) b
  call it(n)

contains

subroutine it(n)
  integer n,j
  integer, dimension(3*(n-1)) :: a
  a = [ (j,j=4,3*n,1) ]
  write(*,*) a
end subroutine it

end program test5
```

Comment: I thought you couldn't use the brackets to specify an array unless it was in an initialization statement.  That was my initial motivation for the code that I have.  Am I stuck on an old standard?

Comment: I think Fortran 2003 allows brackets instead of the (/ ... /) combination everywhere.

Comment: OK, that makes sense and it compiles fine now that I fixed it.  Thanks for the enlightening examples.